# Which is the best django-file manager?

Tags: django

I want to build centralized content repository for department of my college.
Documents doesn't contains any images( So no requirement of thumbnail/cropping etc ).

Which basic package I can use currently.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's trash is another man's treasure.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints.

Comment: Usually questions with "best" in them are dismissed as off-topic and closed/downvoted on sight. Since you're new here I won't downvote you though be advised that many people here are nowhere as forgiving.